# Django Database 1054 error

Tags: python, django

Working on Django currently. I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models

class cliente(models.Model):
    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apellidos   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status      = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        nombreCompleto = "%s %s"%(self.nombre,self.apellidos)
        return nombreCompleto

class producto(models.Model):

    def url(self, filename):
        ruta = "MultimediaData/Producto/%s/%s"%(self.nombre, str(filename))
        return ruta

    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    status      = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    imagen      = models.ImageField(upload_to = url)
    precio      = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2) 
    stock       = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.nombre
```

And when I tried accessing `cliente` and `producto` under the admin, I got the 
`(1054, "Unknown column 'ventas_cliente.apellidos' in 'field list'")` error. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You probably added the `apellidos` column after you did the first `syncdb`. When you syncdb for the first time, tables are created in the database. Afterwards, any changes to your models won't be applied to your database. You have to make the changes yourself with an `ALTER TABLE` SQL command or by dropping the table (if you don't need the data in it) and running `syncdb` again.

I recommend you check [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html):

> South can see what’s changed in your models.py file and automatically write migrations that match your changes.